# How to make copy of the contents of an array without knowing the specific subtype of its contents?

Tags: java, arrays, copy

Say I have an abstract class called SuperClass and many classes extending it. I have an array of of type SuperClass[]. I want to make an array with new objects of the same subclasses and the same attributes.

I tried to do this by creating instantiating new objects and fill the new array with them. However this doesn't work as demonstrated as follows.

```
SuperClass[] newArray = new SuperClass[arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    SuperClass toBeCopied = arr[i];
    newArray[i] = new SuperClass(toBeCopied.attribute1, toBeCopied.attribute2...);
```

This does not work because SuperClass is abstract and thus cannot be instantiated.

I also looked at .clone(), but SuperClass doesn't extend Cloneable.

Are there any other ways of making a copy of an array with unknown content types?

Comment: Have you looked at reflection?

Comment: Have you looked at [Arrays.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int))

Comment: Sure, you can try to distinguish based on the subtype of each object via instanceof and make copies of concrete objects. Refactoring this inconvenient behaviour would be to extend the super class with a abstract copy or clone method.

Comment: @Smutje the problem is that there are too many subclasses which would make my code extremely messy and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Add an `public abstract SuperClass copy()` method to `SuperClass` which then needs to be implemented by every subclass

Comment: @HuLiu Sure, as refactoring this copy to the abstract super class would be the natural "out-sourcing" of the redundant behaviour I desribed as a first approach.

Comment: How about serializing the array and then deserializing it to the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a set of static methods in `Arrays` that can copy an array. For example: `<T> T[] copyOf(T[] original, int newLength)`. Usage:

```java
abstract class SuperClass {  }

class SubClass extends SuperClass {  }

// copy
SuperClass[] subClasses = new SubClass[10];
SuperClass[] subClassesCopy = Arrays.copyOf(subClasses, 10);
```

-- Update --

Since you want copies of each object within the array, you can define an abstract method in `SuperClass` and have the subclasses extend it.

```java
  abstract class SuperClass {

    public abstract SuperClass deepCopy();
  }

  class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    private String value;

    public SubClass(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public SubClass deepCopy() {
      return new SubClass(this.value);
    }
  }
```

And then call `deepCopy` in your code:

```java
    SuperClass[] subClasses = new SubClass[] { new SubClass("1"), new SubClass("2") };

    SuperClass[] subClassesCopy = Arrays.stream(subClasses)
        .map(orig -> orig.deepCopy())
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .toArray(new SuperClass[subClasses.length]);
```

Comment: If I do this, wouldn't the contents of the two arrays point to the same objects?

Comment: Yes the contents themselves reference the same objects in the original array, this creates a copy of the array, ie, the original and copy array references are different. Do you want to create a copy of each object within the array?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a copy of each object within the array.

Comment: Updated the answer as per your requirements.

Comment: Yes it did. I added an abstract copy method in SuperClass then override in all subclasses. This results in I don't have to know the specific types of the contents to make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to do so

```
SuperClass[] newArray = new SuperClass[arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  SuperClass toBeCopied = arr[i];
  newArray[i] = (SuperClass) Class.forName(toBeCopied.getClass().getName())
      .getConstructor(String.class, String.class)
      .newInstance(new Object[] { toBeCopied.getAttribute1(),toBeCopied.getAttribute2() });
}
```

Here i am considering, your constructor with two parameters of String type. If you have different type of parameters then change the type at `.getConstructor(String.class, String.class)`.

Sub Type(Class)

```
public class SubType1 extends SuperClass{
  public SubType1(String attribute1, String attribute2) {
    super(attribute1, attribute2);
  }
}

public class SubType2 extends SuperClass{
  public SubType2(String attribute1, String attribute2) {
    super(attribute1, attribute2);
  }
}
```

Super Class

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
private String attribute1;
private String attribute2;

public SuperClass(String attribute1, String attribute2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.attribute1 = attribute1;
    this.attribute2 = attribute2;
}

public String getAttribute1() {
    return attribute1;
}

public void setAttribute1(String attribute1) {
    this.attribute1 = attribute1;
}

public String getAttribute2() {
    return attribute2;
}

public void setAttribute2(String attribute2) {
    this.attribute2 = attribute2;
}
}
```